# Slow Calendar Control Rendering in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm making a calendar for the whole year to show the holidays of the Year and Events and so on... using displaying 12 Calendar control in a grid each one of the calendars will be limited to a specific month, my problem is the grid takes some time for rendering about 2 seconds,

- how can I improve the performance and display it faster?
- what's the cause of the problem?
- is there a better approach?

I'm using WPF, C#

```
<!--12 Calendar Contents-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Calendar x:Name="JanuaryCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="FebruaryCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="MarchCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="AprilCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="3"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="MayCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="JuneCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="JulyCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="AugustCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="3"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="SeptemberCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="OctoberCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="NovemberCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />

            <Calendar x:Name="DecemberCalendar"
                      Grid.Column="3"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      SelectionMode="SingleDate"
                      IsTodayHighlighted="False"
                      SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged" />


        </Grid>
```

Custom Style

[Calendar Custom Style](https://pastebin.com/KLC6W6kW)

[image: Grid Layout]

Comment: What's the parent of the `Grid`? Please post your full XAML tree including any custom styles.

Comment: Well your grid takes about 100MB to render so this is probably why it takes 1-2 seconds, you could try make your own control and minimize memory usage which will probably help it render faster, also are you running this from an SSD?

Comment: i've edited the post with custom style ,
the parent is Grid

Comment: *it tried to display these calendars in a separate application without styles or anything and it takes the same time to render.